# i want to convert my string to a valid date time string only

Tags: asp.net, datetime

i want to convert my string to a valid date time string only because i get an error that the string is not recognized as a valid date time string and based on the parameters of my function i can only pass a string to my database procedure.
What should i do?
This is my code

```
        DOB = DayList.Text + "-" + MonthList.Text + "-" + YearList.Text;
        string[] var = { "@fn", "@ln", "@em", "@cn", "@dt", "@pswrd", "@gen", "@ques", "@ans", "@dt2" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Char, SqlDbType.Char, SqlDbType.NVarChar, SqlDbType.NVarChar, SqlDbType.DateTime, SqlDbType.NVarChar, SqlDbType.Char, SqlDbType.NVarChar, SqlDbType.NVarChar, SqlDbType.DateTime };
        string[] value = { FirstName.Text, LastName.Text, Email.Text, ContactNumber.Text, DOB, Password.Text, gender.ToString(), QuestionList.Text, QuestionAnswerTextbox.Text, s2 + s1 + s3 };
        cl.executeProcedure("RegisterMemberProcedure",var,type,value);
```

daylist, monthlist and yearlist are dropdown list. Leave your answers please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(DayList.Text + "-" + MonthList.Text + "-" + YearList.Text).Date;

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
string dateTime = DayList.Text + "/" + MonthList.Text + "/" + YearList.Text;
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
```